# How can i fetch and display values in view file in joomla2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I am customizing youtube gallery component to search and display the value in seperate view file. I have create a form to get word to search and display it in same view file.
Here i can able to fetch the values inside view.html.php but cannot able to display it in default.php.I do what i went wrong can anyone help me out as i am new to joomla

Comment: can you show us your `view.html.php` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template file in views->yourview->tmpl folder and name it like as default_templatename and code for display the result.

_templatename is keyword, you can put it anything like default_template1, default_result

After creating template file. You can load it into default.php file by using this:-

```
echo $this->loadTemplate('yourtemplatename');
```

like

```
echo $this->loadTemplate('default_template1');
```